# Solve A$(1+x)^{n}x = Bx + C(1+x)^{n} $

Tags: exponential-function, binomial-theorem

I'm struggling to solve A$(1+x)^{n}x = Bx + C(1+x)^{n}$ for x. The first idea I had was substituting $\tau=(1+x)^{n}$ but it led me nowhere. Trying to use logarithms didn't lead me anywhere either... any hints?

Comment: Are $A,B,C$ constants? replace $x=0,$ gives you $C=0$. Replace $x=-1$ gives $B=0.$ Is there anything else in the problem?

Comment: This is an $n+1$ degree polynomial, which in general will have $n+1$ (complex) solutions, and which in general cannot be solved analytically for $n+1 \geq 4.$ There are a number of ways to find numerical solutions for any given $A, B, C.$ Note that you can divide by $A$ to get $B/A = b, C/A =c.$ reducing the complexity somewhat. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintic_function